# How to avoid using setProps in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working on application using `react & redux` and I need setProps but it's deprecated.

Take a look the error below:

> Warning: setProps(...) and replaceProps(...) are deprecated. Instead,
>   call render again at the top level.
>
> Uncaught Invariant Violation: setProps(...): You called `setProps` on
>   a component with a parent. This is an anti-pattern since props will
>   get reactively updated when rendered. Instead, change the owner's
>   `render` method to pass the correct value as props to the component
>   where it is created.

So how can I set the props? basically is to manage some tabs, take a look below my code:

```
export default React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
         <div className="demo-tabs">
             <Tabs activeTab={this.props.activeTab}
                   onChange={(tabId) => this.setProps({ activeTab: tabId })} ripple>
                 <Tab>Stack</Tab>
                 <Tab>GitHub</Tab>
                 <Tab>Twitter</Tab>
             </Tabs>
             <section>
                 <div className="content">Content for the tab: {this.props.activeTab}</div>
             </section>
         </div>
     );
  }
});
```

Container

```
import React from 'react';
import TimeLine from './timeline';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getStackoverflow } from 'api/timeline';

const TimeLineContainer = React.createClass({

    componentWillMount: function() {
      getStackoverflow();
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <TimeLine {...this.props} />
        )
    }
});

const stateToProps = function(state) {
    return {
        timeline: state.timelineReducer.timeline
    }
}

const dispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
    return {
        onClick: () => {console.log('timeline was clicked')}
    }
}

export default connect(stateToProps, dispatchToProps)(TimeLineContainer)
```

Reducer

```
var timelineInitialState = {
  github:         [],
  gist:           [],
  stackoverflow:  [],
  twitter:        [],
  activeTab:      2
}

export default function(state = timelineInitialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_GITHUB':
      //TODO: implement.
      break;
    case 'GET_GIST':
      //TODO: implement.
      break;
    case 'GET_STACKOVERFLOW':
      var stackoverflowState = Object.assign({}, state)
      stackoverflowState.stackoverflow = action.stackoverflow;
      return stackoverflowState;
      break;
    case 'GET_TWITTER':
      //TODO: implement.
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the props you need to set yourself  should be internal state and you should call setState instead. Or keep the prop but make it set the state when it changes (sync prop and state)

Comment: Like @JuanMendes said, you will want to use state. What you can do is set your initial state using your props and then going forward set the updated value to state

Comment: @realseanp you have to make sure you implement `componentWillReceiveProps` so it updates the state when the parent component sets a prop after the initial render

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It looks like you dived into using Redux without first getting a firm grip of React. I wouldn’t recommend doing this because you appear to be somewhat confused now.

[Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) is a great guide and I recommend you to go through it first and get comfortable with the idea of state ownership in React, before using Redux.

In React, things that change over time (“state”) are always “owned” by some component. Sometimes it’s the same component that uses this state for rendering. Sometimes many components need to be synchronized so the state gets “hoisted” to some parent component that can manage them all, and pass that information via props. Whenever state changes, they all get updated.

The important part here is that `props` are meant to be received by parent. If a component wants to change its own props, it is a symptom of a problem:

1. Either you should have used `state` for this component, so you can call `setState`
2. Or your component needs to access a callback prop like `onChange` so it can “ask” the value to be changed

In the first case, your code would look like this, and it would be valid React:

```
export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { activeTab: 0 }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
         <div className="demo-tabs">
             <Tabs activeTab={this.state.activeTab}
                   onChange={(tabId) => this.setState({ activeTab: tabId })} ripple>
                 <Tab>Stack</Tab>
                 <Tab>GitHub</Tab>
                 <Tab>Twitter</Tab>
             </Tabs>
             <section>
                 <div className="content">Content for the tab: {this.state.activeTab}</div>
             </section>
         </div>
     );
  }
});
```

However, you can continue the pattern you are already using with `<Tabs>` component inside, and hoist the state even higher. Then your component would need to accept an `onChange` prop which it would pass down to `<Tabs>`. Now it doesn’t know *how* the state is updated, and doesn’t hold the state:

```
export default React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
         <div className="demo-tabs">
             <Tabs activeTab={this.props.activeTab}
                   onChange={this.props.onChange} ripple>
                 <Tab>Stack</Tab>
                 <Tab>GitHub</Tab>
                 <Tab>Twitter</Tab>
             </Tabs>
             <section>
                 <div className="content">Content for the tab: {this.props.activeTab}</div>
             </section>
         </div>
     );
  }
});
```

Neither approach is better or worse, they are used for different purposes. The first one is more convenient when the state is irrelevant to the rest of the app, the second one is convenient when other distant components happen to need it too. Make sure you understand the tradeoffs of both approaches.

Even with the second approach, *something*’s got to hold the state. It could be another component, or (and this is where Redux comes in) it could be a separate data storage like a Redux store. In this case, rather than supply `onChange` from a parent component, you would use `connect()` to bind an `onChange` prop it injects to dispatching a Redux action:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    activeTabId: state.activeTabId
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onChange: (tabId) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_ACTIVE_TAB', tabId })
  }
}
```

And in your reducers, you can handle this action:

```
const activeTabId = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'SET_ACTIVE_TAB':
    return action.tabId
  default:
    return state
  }
}

const reducer = combineReducers({
  activeTabId,
  // other reducers
})

const store = createStore(reducer)
```

In neither case we need `setProps`. You can either:

- let the component own the state and use `setState`,
- let it accept the `activeTabId` and `onChange` props and manage them from a component higher in the tree that would use `setState`, or
- you can move the state handling completely out of the components into something like Redux, but your components would still accept `activeTabId` and `onChange` as props.

Answer (score 2):

Provide onTabChange callback to Timeline component from Container.

Container:

```
const dispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
    return {
        onClick: () => {console.log('timeline was clicked')},
        onTabChange: (tabId) => { setActiveTabAction(tabId) }
    }
}
const stateToProps = function(state) {
    return {
        timeline: state.timelineReducer.timeline,
        activeTab: state.timelineReducer.activeTab
    }
}
```

Timeline component:

```
export default React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
         <div className="demo-tabs">
             <Tabs activeTab={this.props.activeTab}
                   onChange={this.props.onTabChange} ripple>
                 <Tab>Stack</Tab>
                 <Tab>GitHub</Tab>
                 <Tab>Twitter</Tab>
             </Tabs>
             <section>
                 <div className="content">Content for the tab: {this.props.activeTab}</div>
             </section>
         </div>
     );
  }
});
```

Presentational components (like your Timeline component) usually shouldn't manage application state. All data and callbacks they must receive by props.

I suggest you to read article about Presentational and Container components:
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.sijqpzk93